# Display a span slowly(Animation) on clicking first span using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display a span slowly by using animate function in jquery. But, anyhow it displays it like nothing.My code is

```
$(this).hide().siblings('span').show().animate({width: "100"}, 1000);
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/781/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you wanted? -> http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/h4JXs/787/

Comment: You should really show your real html, since you are trying to show a div that is already visible? What do you intend to accomplish? If you want to show an element slowly, it should be hidden at first, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.share-text').click(function(){                    
          $(this).hide('slow').siblings('span').show('slow'); 
      });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/782/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   $('.share-text').click(function(){    

      $(this).siblings('span').slideToggle();
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/785/)